# Some Reviewed Low Quality Answers are not being deleted

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

There's an odd thing going on with some NAA/LQP reviews. The reviews are being completed and the flags are clearing, but the post is not being deleted. Hat tip to CertainPerformance for [noting the pattern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55261379#55261379)

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73764843/timeline (10k now)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73766270/timeline
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73735046/timeline
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71077213/timeline
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73165164/timeline
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72915546/timeline

They all look like this

[image: NAA flag cleared]

As you can see, [that review got 4 votes for deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32728395), with two of them coming from 20k users ("Delete" vs "Recommend Deletion"). The answer has no upvotes, so the review completion should have triggered a delete.

There are two possibilities I can think of for why deletion didn't occur:

- Server problems - Things were behaving wonky around the time of these reviews, at least on Stack Overflow, at 9-19 between 00:30 and 03:00 UTC. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767377), [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55247336#55247336), [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55247386#55247386), and [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55247599#55247599) for observations. Issues included (but may not have been limited to) failures to edit posts, failures to delete posts when the delete-voter should have the ability to do so singlehandedly, and [failures of Mjolnir](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55247390#55247390) to dupe-hammer a question.

  The timeframe of these problems was relatively short, so if this happened to be the cause of the review problems too, all that's needed to fix things on the LQA front is for a diamond mod to delete the posts that fell through the cracks. The reviews listed above look to be the only ones affected, at least in LQA on Stack Overflow; no problems were seen on a cursory glance at the Close and Reopen queue history around those times. There may well be a decent handful of other actions outside of review that failed for many users, but were too intermittent for anyone to post a bug report, so it's pretty hard to track down issues unless the votes -> resulting actions process is made to recalculate what all was done during that time, if that's the sort of thing that can be triggered manually. Other sites may have experienced this too, but I haven't checked.
- Userscript problems - there's a small chance that [the userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420466/some-reviewed-low-quality-answers-are-not-being-deleted?noredirect=1#comment927603_420466) being used by one of the reviewers was interfering with things (though it's been used for years without issues like these being seen before).

Comment: RE delete votes: I use a userscript to tweak the review payload so as not to spend my delete votes (otherwise I sometimes find I'm out when I want to delete something), but I've noticed that it does still come up as "Delete" in timelines. (Perhaps that process checks rep rather than endpoint hit to determine which string to print.) So, after the review completes, if the post remains visible, I'd expect to see only a single pending delete vote for the post. Perhaps the other reviewer is using a similar userscript?

Comment: Perhaps the review task not deleting the post is the result of the [mild site instability](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55247336#55247336) that was going on a day or two ago - other votes were failing to have their intended effect as well ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767874/))

Comment: @CertainPerformance You don't show up in the timeline as having cast a delete vote on any of the examples above... so... maybe it's your userscript that's causing this issue?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you share the userscript in question? I'd like to see what calls it's making.

Comment: Code: https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/a22ac42a81a7ae80b360910f9864be5b It's not impossible, but I don't think the userscript is the issue because (1) It's so similar (2) SE was having server issues at the same time (2022-09-19 00:30:00Z to 2022-09-19 03:00:00Z, reported by multiple others) and I haven't seen this before (been using it for multiple years) or since.

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's context that would be really useful to have in the question - I'm sure Machavity would be fine with you adding any additional details that might help us identify the issue here? If this was a temporary issue, there's likely not a bug to fix so much as needing to identify any answers that should have been deleted during that period of server issues and double check whether they were deleted or not as expected. :)

Comment: Another case where this may have occured: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78018378

Comment: @janw In that case the question had a positive score. There was an auto flag for mod review that stated so. That's normal